# Erros when executing "cordova emulate android"

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

**igor@igor:~/hellowworld$ cordova emulate android**

Running command: /home/igor/hellowworld/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_10_API_22
Waiting for emulator...

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn EACCES
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
Error: /home/igor/hellowworld/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)

Comment: Is there a question or context here?

Comment: I got this error and I hope someone can help me to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EACCESS error is normally because of permission. Did you executed the command with sudo?

Sometimes I also solved the error giving permissions to

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /appfolder
```